# <itunes:duration> wrong on RSS feed created by Jekyll

Tags: rss, jekyll, podcast

I have a Jekyll site that I have a podcast feed that I created.

```
---
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <atom:link href="http://mikewills.me/rss-podcast.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <title>{{ site.name }}</title>
        <description>{{ site.description }}</description>
        <link>{{ site.url }}</link>
        {% for post in site.categories.podcast limit:15 %}
            <item>
                <title>{{ post.title }}</title>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[
                    {{ post.content | xml_escape }}
                    ]]>
                </description>
                <pubDate>{{ post.date | date: "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z" }}</pubDate>
                <link>{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}</link>
                <guid isPermaLink="true">{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}</guid>
                {% if post.podcasturl %}<enclosure url="{{ post.podcasturl }}" length="{{ post.podcastsize }}" type="{{ post.podcasttype }}" />{% endif %}
            </item>
        {% endfor %}
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Everything else works except for the `<itunes:duration>` tag. When I enter in `podcastlength: 2:07` it outputs as `<itunes:duration>127.0</itunes:duration>`. Based on what I have researched, this is how everyone else is outputting the length. For some reason Jekyll seems to be breaking that down to seconds instead of 2 minutes and 7 seconds. What might I be doing wrong here?

If you are interested, full RSS source is [here](https://github.com/MikeWills/mikewills.github.io/blob/master/rss-podcast.xml) and an example post is [here](https://github.com/MikeWills/mikewills.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2014-07-29-mwp001.md).

Comment: What if you put commas around "2.07" to force Jekyll to think of it as a string and hence not convert it?

Comment: Hmm... I guess programming at midnight isn't best for me. I didn't think of that. I'll take a look later today to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Julien Genestoux suggested worked.

"What if you put commas around "2.07" to force Jekyll to think of it as a string and hence not convert it? –  Julien Genestoux Jul 30 at 13:31"

Answer (score 1):

Hey from the far future.

I ran in to exactly this issue last week. Spotify reached out to me explaning i had somehow managed to get a decimal number (instead of a time-stamp) in my podcast feed.

Hey I had this exact issue!

In my post.markdown file I had written:

```
audio_mp3_duration: 35:56
---
```

The fun thing with the liquid programming language here is that it will somehow try to calculate the above, so I had to specifically wrap my string like so:

```
audio_mp3_duration: '43:01'
---
```

Turns out it was this exact problem ;)

Answer (score -1):

The `<itunes:duration>` tag must contain data in this format:

> HH:MM:SS

therefore, in your specific case, 2 minutes and 7 seconds should be

```
<itunes:duration>2:07</itunes:duration>
```

See also the [official podcast specs by Apple](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/techspecs.html).

In case Jekyll doesn't convert the duration to the proper format, it could be a bug and you should notify the developers.